# Basic While loops doesn't print anything

Tags: c, while-loop, logical-operators

I'm trying to create a while loop in C, it says that build is successful, however it doesn't print out anything. I don't really see whats wrong, it doesn't show anything in the console.

```
int main()
{
  int w = 0;
  while (w >=100){
    printf("w = %i" , w);
    w++;
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `while (w >= 100)` is never true as `w` is 0 and `0 >= 100` is false. Did you mean `while (w <= 100)`? BTW, indent your code properly and tag it with correct tags.

Comment: Why is this considered off topic?  @ABCCode is clearly learning the basics of C loops.

Answer (score 6):

You define `w=0` and in the next line you write "while w is greater or equal than 100", which cannot work.

Try

```
while (w <= 100)
```